# TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH is not defined during Travis build

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, travis-ci

I'm trying to get my js script to pull the TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH value but it comes up undefined when my js script runs.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

**deploy-pull-request.js**

```
const chalk = require('chalk'),
  _ = require('lodash'),
  green = chalk.green,
  info = chalk.yellow,
  Deploy = require('./deployApi')

  // require('dotenv').config()

// const { env } = process
  let options = {
    awsKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    awsSecret: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    localBuildFolder: 'build',
    domain: 'admin-'
}

const branch = process.env.FAKE_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH || process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH
```

.. rest of the code...

**travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 8
cache:
  yarn: true
  directories:
    - node_modules
deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
before_script:
  - pip install --user awscli
  - yarn run build
  - yarn run test
script:
  - babel-node ./src/client/deploy/deploy-pull-request.js
```